# Is a reaction involving hadrons always strong (given conservation laws are satisfied)?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, strong-force

This question is partly related to two of my earlier questions: [If a particle interaction does not violate conservation laws will it occur?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276333/if-a-particle-interaction-does-not-violate-conservation-laws-will-it-occur) and [Could $p+p\rightarrow \pi^++d$ occur via the weak interaction?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309893/could-pp-rightarrow-pid-occur-via-the-weak-interaction)

Consider the reaction between a set of initial hadrons $H_1,...,H_n$ to produce a set of final hadrons $F_1,...,F_m$ i.e.

$$H_1+...+H_n \rightarrow F_1+...+F_m$$
let us assume all the relevant conservation laws for the strong interaction are satisfied. Will the (and can the) interaction always occur (with largest probability) through the strong interaction?

Comment: What do you mean by "will the interaction always occur through the strong interaction"? If a given interaction can occur both through the strong and the weak force, you cannot tell which one "really" happened. Feynman diagrams don't depict actual processes, they depict perturbative contributions to a total amplitude. Asking whether any particular instance of a process occurs "through the strong force" or "through the weak force" is not a meaningful question, so I don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I am asking if conservation laws are satisfied then can we assume that the interaction does occur through the strong force (by at least one route). And secondly will this route be that of greatest probability.

Comment: The ρ decays strongly. It *could* conceivably  decay weakly as well--why not? But you did cover in the first week of your particle physics course that its (strong decay, actual) width is 150MeV, and that of its weak decays would be *16 orders of magnitude smaller* (compare it with the weak width of the K+).  It is always nice to juxtapose a blade of grass to a forest, but, just perhaps, archetypally academic.

Comment: @ACuriousMind maybe read as "if the strong conservation laws are all satisfied, can we assume that the leading terms to the amplitude come from the strong force diagrams?"

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in general, if a process is not forbidden, then it is mandatory.

There are some subtleties with regard to approximate and accidental symmetries. For example, isospin is an approximate (and fairly good) symmetry of the strong interaction, and not a symmetry at all of QED. As a result, an isospin violating reaction among hadrons, allowed by QCD, may proceed predominantly by QED.

Answer (score 2):

Talking of particle interactions is talking about quantum mechanics.

Quantum mechanics has specific mathematical tools to calculate the probabilities of specific interactions, weak , strong, electromagnetic.

If all the energy rules and all the quantum number conservations are obeyed an interaction  will happen with virtual particle exchanges transferring energy and momentum and quantum numbers for all three forces. The only way one can see if this is happening is if there is an exact calculation, and a good enough measurement accuracy to show that the crossection measured has contributions from more than one exchanges. That is why the strength of the interactions are important. With the [strength of the strong at 1, the electromagnetic is 1/137 and the weak order of 10^6.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html).

Every vertex entering in the interaction multiplies by this order of magnitude , so even that there might exist equivalent Feynman diagrams, the strong predominates and it is very hard to see the weak. It is only when strong interactions are excluded by conservation laws that the effect of the electromagnetic and the weak can be seen in measured crossections and lifetimes.